# KonvaJS - Text bounding box around KonvaText without top,bottom space

Tags: konvajs, konva

What would be the best way to create a bounding box around KonvaText, without any padding or space in
between the top and bottom?

The blue colour box is the current bounding box, and the requirement is to remove the top and bottom space like in the green line. So the final result should be a bounding box similar to the existing one, but without top, bottom space like in the green lines.

Highly appreciate if someone can help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be not simple to do for any font. Text rendering and position of every character can vary a lot, depending on the font used.

As a workaround, you can just create a smaller rectangle, that fits your required position, and then just map all its properties into `Konva.Text`.

```
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const text = new Konva.Text({
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  text: 'Some text',
  fill: 'green',
  fontSize: 40,
});
layer.add(text);


const box = new Konva.Rect({
  x: text.x(),
  y: text.y(),
  width: text.width(),
  // make height smaller
  height: text.height() - 5,
  draggable: true
});
layer.add(box);

box.on('dragmove transform', () => {
  text.setAttrs({
    x: box.x(),
    y: box.y(),
    scaleX: box.scaleX(),
    scaleY: box.scaleY()
  })
})

const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
  nodes: [box],
});
layer.add(tr);

layer.draw();
```

https://jsbin.com/kecunonopa/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Great. Thanks lavrton. Will  **height: text.height() - 5** work for all the cases? Does it have any way to get the reducing figure dynamically?

Comment: Yes. You can draw font into external canvas -> get its image data -> check all pixels to find bounding box of a font and its "padding".